# Npm run server doest work/ cant run server with

Tags: node.js, npm

command "npm run serve" doest work, and i get this:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT 
> npm ERR! syscall open 
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\user/package.json 
> npm ERR! errno -4058 
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\package.json' 
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. 
> npm ERR! enoent 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: <>br
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-24T23_43_08_331Z-debug-0.log

I tried reinstalling/ installing the node, npm, i tried and didnt work: 
npm config set ignore-scripts false

Comment: It looks like you are running `npm run serve` from a directory that does not have a package.json. You will need to be in a directory that has a package.json with a [`"scripts"` section](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#description) that has a `"serve"` script specified. You most likely need to move into the directory of your project and run your command again. You might need to run `npm install` first depending on whether your dependencies have already been installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are executing NPM from your user home directory. You need to run it in a project directory, and then run `npm init`, along with the corresponding `npm install <X>` commands. Do not run init if the project is already initialized.